# Why hibernate not including all modified properties of an entity in dirtyProperties array?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hibernate is not including the property annotated by Javax.Persistence.Version in dirtyProperties list which is provided by the PostUpdateEvent. Is this the default behavior of Hibernate? If yes can I configure which properties it should not blacklist?

Comment: To the close vote: how is this opinion based? Either it is the default behavior, or it isn't. Either it is configurable or it isn't. No opinion involved.

Comment: You can check `org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister#findDirty` or `org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister#findModified` to understand why the version is not included.